# Flex 3 - Force all controls to render at start

Tags: apache-flex

When I try to access the hidden TABs of my tab navigator control in action script, it returns a null error.  But it works OK if I just activate the control in the user interface once.  Obviously the control is not created until I use it.  How do I make all the tabs automatically created by default ?

Comment: You have to ask yourself why you are trying to access a tab, or anyother control for that matter,  that is not instantiated. If you can use a dataprovider or other bindable property there is no reason you can not set that variable.

Comment: @AndrewB - Yes, you are right. In my case I am using one XML object as the data provider for both the TABs (tabs contain tree controls) and setting it dynamically in code. It so happens when the user does something on the interface, I have to move her to the uninitialized tab and before that I am trying to set the dataprovider property of the tree control... hence the error. may be I should have separate data providers for each tab and just update them and the TAB will pick it up as necessary. But your line of reasoning is the right way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<mx:TabNavigator creationPolicy="all"/>
```

That should do it. Deferred instanciation is a feature, but sometimes it is a hassle.

Comment: Ya, that is always kind of a weird "WTF". You should go ahead and accept the answer if it worked. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Flex framework is optimizing creation be default (creationPolicy="auto") so if you have a configuration dialog with a lot of tabs, for example, and the most useful tab is the first one, your application does not spend time and memory initializing the tabs that the user never sees.

This makes a lot of difference when dialogs like this never release, and is a good default to go with.

One thing to look at is using a private variable in your dialog/form instead of pushing the data to the control on the hidden page. This style treats the whole form as if it were a component, which it sort of is. To repeat: the MXML form/dialog/canvas is a class, and it can have data and methods in addition to containing other components.

Cheers

Comment: On that note, if you have some shared data-level variable which is being used throughout several views, then it might be a better idea to break it out to a separate class, and just pass it around via the object reference, or make it static and [Bindable]. This way, you can choose when and how to initialize the data, and just bind against it globally or via some access routine. This also appeases the Software Design gods by separating the UI from the underlying data model.

However, if the variable is another UI element, then take a look at the creationComplete event.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, I've run into the deferred-loading policy in a multi-state application, and circumvented it by forcing all elements to be included and invisible in the initial state. Something to consider, but only as a hack.